# WPF hierarchicaldatatemplate Filter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have in `ViewModel`

```
public string SearchPattern
{
    get
    {
        return searchPattern;
    }

    set
    {
        searchPattern = value;
    }
}

private bool UserFilter(object item)
{
    return (item as Node).Name.Contains(SearchPattern);
}

public ICollectionView YourFilteredCollection
{
    get
    {
        var source = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(model.Items);
        source.Filter = UserFilter;
        return source;
    }
}
```

`YourFilteredCollection` depends on `Model` property

```
 public ObservableCollection<Node> Items { get; set; }
```

Than I decided to filter Node sub items `YourFilteredCollectionNodes`

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

    public ICollectionView YourFilteredCollectionNodes
    {
        get
        {
            var source = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Nodes);
            if (source != null)
            {
                source.Filter = UserFilter;
            }
            return source;
        }
    }

    private bool UserFilter(object item)
    {
        //return (item as Node).Name.Contains(SearchPattern);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But in this case how it is possible to pass `SearchPattern` from ViewModel in `ObservableCollection` item that is in Model??

Comment: Maybe you can keep a `Parent` property in your `Node` class and then access SearchPattern at each level through it?

Comment: @dotNET, can you post example?